# How to use regex delimiter to handle special case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a string like this and the delimiter is | char,

```
string = "1234|Google | Alphabet|pest||pp| |||r"
```

the output I am looking for is,

```
[1234, Google | Alphabet, pest, "", pp, " ", "", "", r]
```

I used this,

```
output = re.split("(?<=\w)\|(?=\w)", string) # but this is giving me wrong output
```

The issue here is `Google | Alphabet` is a single word since `|` is separated by space on both ends. Basically if a `|` is present with space on both sides its part of that word itself else split it. Can someone tell me a good regex to split it properly. I want to use this regex in `pandas.read_csv`.

I can write a code to handle this manually but I am looking for a better approach to use as a `sep (i.e., since it support regex)` in `pd.read_csv`

Thank you.

Comment: just split and join the ones you claim to be 1 word

Comment: @onyambu But I won't be able to do it directly in `pd.read_csv` right?

Comment: read in the data as in `pd.read_csv(..., sep = '|')` then from there join the two wods that need to be one

Answer (score 1):

You could also split asserting not a whitespace char to the left or to the right:

```
\|(?!\s)|(?<!\s)\|
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1m7GqN/1) | [python demo](https://ideone.com/4Z6TDA)

```
import re

s = "1234|Google | Alphabet|pest||pp| |||r"

print(re.split(r"\|(?!\s)|(?<!\s)\|", s))
```

Output

```
['1234', 'Google | Alphabet', 'pest', '', 'pp', ' ', '', '', 'r']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\|(?<!\s\|(?=\s))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNkSaC/1). *Details*:

- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(?<!\s\|(?=\s))` - that is not immediately preceded with a whitespace and immediately followed with a whitespace.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vOZaqu):

```py
import re
s = "1234|Google | Alphabet|pest||pp| |||r"
print( re.split(r'\|(?<!\s\|(?=\s))', s) )
# => ['1234', 'Google | Alphabet', 'pest', '', 'pp', ' ', '', '', 'r']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
import re

s = "1234|Google | Alphabet|pest||pp| |||r"

sep = r"(?:(?<=\S)\|(?=\S))|(?:(?<=\s)\|(?=\S))|(?:(?<=\S)\|(?=\s))"

print(re.split(sep, s))
```

Prints:

```
['1234', 'Google | Alphabet', 'pest', '', 'pp', ' ', '', '', 'r']
```